# Creating a BMI table

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a BMI table with a column for height from 58 inches to 76 inches in 2-inch increments and a row for weight from 100 pounds to 250 pounds in 10-pound increments, I've got the row and the column, but I can't figure out how to calculate the different BMI's within the table.

This is my code:

```py
header = '\t{}'.format('\t'.join(map(str, range(100, 260, 10))))
rows = []
for i in range(58, 78, 2):
  row = '\t'.join(map(str, (bmi for q in range(1, 17))))
  rows.append('{}\t{}'.format(i, row))
  print(header + '\n' + '\n'.join(rows))
```

This is the output:

```py
  100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250
58 
60  
62  
64  
66  
68  
70  
72  
74  
76
```

What I'm trying to do is fill in the chart. For example, a height of 58 inches and 100 pounds is a BMI of 22.4. A height of 58 inches and 110 pounds is 24.7, and so on.

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to calculate the different BMI's within the table."* OK, but what is your question? Be specific, include your expected results, and explain how your actual results are different. We can't guess what you want the result to be if you don't tell us! See also [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got your expected results of 22.4 and 22.7, but if you define BMI to be weight [lb] / (height [in])^2 * 703, you could do something like the following:

```
In [16]: weights = range(100, 260, 10)
    ...: header = '\t' + '\t'.join(map(str, weights))
    ...: rows = [header]
    ...: for height in range(58, 78, 2):
    ...:     row = '\t'.join(f'{weight/height**2*703:.1f}' for weight in weights)
    ...:     rows.append(f'{height}\t{row}')
    ...: print('\n'.join(rows))
    ...:
        100     110     120     130     140     150     160     170     180     190     200     210     220     230     240     250
58      20.9    23.0    25.1    27.2    29.3    31.3    33.4    35.5    37.6    39.7    41.8    43.9    46.0    48.1    50.2    52.2
60      19.5    21.5    23.4    25.4    27.3    29.3    31.2    33.2    35.1    37.1    39.1    41.0    43.0    44.9    46.9    48.8
62      18.3    20.1    21.9    23.8    25.6    27.4    29.3    31.1    32.9    34.7    36.6    38.4    40.2    42.1    43.9    45.7
64      17.2    18.9    20.6    22.3    24.0    25.7    27.5    29.2    30.9    32.6    34.3    36.0    37.8    39.5    41.2    42.9
66      16.1    17.8    19.4    21.0    22.6    24.2    25.8    27.4    29.0    30.7    32.3    33.9    35.5    37.1    38.7    40.3
68      15.2    16.7    18.2    19.8    21.3    22.8    24.3    25.8    27.4    28.9    30.4    31.9    33.4    35.0    36.5    38.0
70      14.3    15.8    17.2    18.7    20.1    21.5    23.0    24.4    25.8    27.3    28.7    30.1    31.6    33.0    34.4    35.9
72      13.6    14.9    16.3    17.6    19.0    20.3    21.7    23.1    24.4    25.8    27.1    28.5    29.8    31.2    32.5    33.9
74      12.8    14.1    15.4    16.7    18.0    19.3    20.5    21.8    23.1    24.4    25.7    27.0    28.2    29.5    30.8    32.1
76      12.2    13.4    14.6    15.8    17.0    18.3    19.5    20.7    21.9    23.1    24.3    25.6    26.8    28.0    29.2    30.4
```

What's probably keeping you down in your own code is the `for q in range(1, 17)` which you'll want to turn into your weights instead; you could just replace it with `for q in range(100, 260, 10)` and use the formula directly if you liked, but here we just avoid the duplication by introducing `weights`.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now. I was most likely overthinking it putting down `for q in range(1, 17)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove the indent print statement at the end. Running this code with the indent prints out one table as each row is put in. Secondly, the snippet of code you will want to change is

(bmi for q in range(1, 17))

Since BMI is a function of mass and height, I would change your iterator i to height, q to mass, and range(1, 17) to range(100, 260, 10). This is to improve readability. Then, replace bmi with an expression using mass and height that returns bmi. For example,

(mass*height for mass in range(100, 260, 10))

I don't believe BMI=mass*height, but replace this with the real formula.